# how to use a USB Webcamera without NDK?

Tags: android

I am trying to connect USB web camera to my Android phone and capture images using the web camera. I want to do this without using any Library. As far as I see, I could not find any Android API to support USB web camera. I see a lot of applications on the PlayStore doing the job.